# ruby 1.9.2 and rails 2.3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can any body tell me please how to run ruby 1.9.2 and rails 2.3.2   its requirement please...
I installed ruby1.9.2 and my client insisted me to work with rails 2.3.2 so i installed rails server using ruby gem with -v option but server is not starting with ruby script/server command it is saying

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Tele\Desktop\rubygems-1.8.24\testapp>ruby script/serve
r
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require':
cannot load such file -- script/../config/boot (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
n `require'
        from script/server:2:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Does the file exist that it's trying to `require`?

Comment: Try generating a new project, as a test, and see if it will start. Is it possible you created this project with a different version of Rails?  Is the file in config/boot there?

Answer (score 1):

Use RVM (Ruby Version Manager) and you can seemlessly manage your ruby and rails versions.

Here's the info:  https://rvm.io//

I know hundreds of Ruby programmers and everyone uses it.  It's basically a standard at this point.

Comment: I'd prefer rbenv. It's less hacky.

Comment: thank you for your replay....installed it 5ne but i have to use mysql as db and i am using windows as platform. I used gems 1.3.2, while installing mysql-ruby gems its saying mysql-config file is missing what exactly that error indicate will you please reply i have very less time to do this...

Answer (score 0):

finally i just did it by using instant rails and gems 1.3.2 and then upgrading my rails version to 2.3.2 any way i compromised my ruby version to 1.8.6